# Write a python program to display all the common characters between two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def firstAndLast(first,last):
    common = []
    if first in last:
        print first

first = list(raw_input("Enter first name: "))
last = list(raw_input("Enter last name: "))

firstAndLast(first, last)
```

#### ERROR:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-f4ec192dd3a8>", line 11
    print names
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(names)?
```

Comment: do `print(first)` instead of `print first`. Secondly, the error is different from the code, so please post the full code

Comment: this is the full code:
def firstAndLast(first,last):
    common = []
    if first in last:
        print (first)


first = list(raw_input("Enter first name: ")
last = list(raw_input("Enter last name: ")

firstAndLast(first, last)

Error:
  File "<ipython-input-14-53ebecc5e8ea>", line 8
    last = list(raw_input("Enter last name: ")
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: add this code, to the question

Comment: First thing to do if you have an error: read the error message!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what to do.
In python-3.x print() is function is with parentheses, so you've to pass the arguments in the parentheses.

```
print(first)
```

And you can also just use `input()` function instead of `raw_input()` function

***PROGRAM***

```
def firstAndLast(first,last):
    common = []
    for letter in first:
        if letter in last:
            common.append(letter)
    return common

first = input("Enter first name: ")
last = input("Enter last name: ")

common = firstAndLast(first, last)
#common will be the list of common letters

print(common)
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Enter first name: janee
Enter last name: denver
['n', 'e', 'e']
```

Comment: That is because your program is wrong. It is checking if the list of characters(of the first word) is in the list of characters of the second word and that's obviously not possible. It doesn't check for common characters. Do you want me to write the correct program?

Comment: actually I have no idea what next to do

Answer (score 0):

Program:

```py
s1=raw_input("Enter first string:")

s2=raw_input("Enter second string:")

a=list(set(s1)&set(s2))

print("The common letters are:")

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hope it will help you

Comment: Update My Answer hope it will help you

Comment: I cant buddy because today is my first day on stack overflow i was not permitted to you answer upvote sry bro beacuse my reputation is only 1

Answer (score 0):

s1=input("Enter first string:")

s2=input("Enter second string:")

a=list(set(s1)&set(s2))

print("The common letters are:")

for i in a: print(i)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
first = list(input("Enter first name: "))
last = list(input("Enter last name: "))

print(f"common characters are: {', '.join(set(first) & set(last))}")
```

output:

```py
Enter first name: Jaydip
Enter last name: Kyada
common characters are: a, y, d
```

I think this single line will answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can `numpy'sintersect1D` :-

```
import numpy as np
def firstAndLast(first,last):
    return np.intersect1d(first, last)

first = input("Enter first name: ")
last = input("Enter last name: ")
first, last = [*first], [*last]

firstAndLast(first, last)
```

**Output**

```
Enter first name: gaurav
Enter last name: chowdhary
array(['a', 'r'], dtype='<U1')
```